# Differentiate between same node names in PHP XPath

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I am using **PHP DOM XPath** to read **XML**. XML is having following structure where I got stuck

```
<details>
    <name>name1</name>
    <address>address1</address>
</details>
<details>
    <name>name2</name>
    <mobile>mobileNum</mobile>
    <address>address2</address>
</details>
```

I have array like

```
  array(
        'name',
        'mobile',
        'address'
    );
```

I use this array and read values from XML and store that values in other array but in the first record **mobile number** is not present so it read mobile no from second record and inserts it in first record.

Expected output is

```
array
(

    [0] => array(

                'person_name' = name1,
                'address' = address1
                )
    [1] => array(

                'person_name' = name1,
                'mobile_no' = mobileNum
                'address' = address1
                )
)
```

But I get output as

```
array
(

    [0] => array(

                'person_name' = name1,
                'mobile_no' = mobileNum
                'address' = address1
                )
    [1] => array(

                'person_name' = name1,
                'address' = address1
                )
)
```

How can I differentiate values between two nodes with same name.

Code to read XML is

```
$nodes = array
(
    'person_name' => 'name',
    'mobile_no'   => 'mobile',
    'address'     => 'address'
)

$final_data = array();

$node_values = '';

foreach($nodes as $key => $data)
{   
    $node_values = $xml->xpath('//details'.$data); 

    $node_values = json_decode(json_encode((array)$node_values), TRUE);

    if(!empty($node_values))    
    {   
        $i = 0;

        foreach($node_values as $d)
        {
            $final_data[$i][$key] = trim($d[0]);

            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your __code__ please.

Comment: Such approach is wrong, Iterate over `details`

Comment: then what can be other way so I can get data correctly.Is there any other possibility to read

Comment: I said - iterate over `details` nodes.

Comment: means like   $xml->xpath('//details/*)

Comment: I travel details as   foreach($xml->xpath('//details/*') as $d){  } it gives all values but problem remains same can not make relations in values

Comment: `$xml` is undefined in your code. Please add code that shows how you create it. Also your code have syntax errors, so I guess that's not the real code, you're using.  Provide working example to let us reproduce your situation.

Comment: Actual XML size and node list is too long so I created example. I will try to add required things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with comments explaining how it works:

https://3v4l.org/ICO5i

```
<?php

// First of all, I've added <root> element to your XML document,
// because otherwise it's invalid. 
// But it's not important for the rest of the code.
//
// Also I've added additional <somethingelse> tag to show that filtering is working
$xmlString = '<root><details>
    <name>name1</name>
    <address>address1</address>
</details>
<details>
    <name>name2</name>
    <mobile>mobileNum</mobile>
    <address>address2</address>
    <somethingelse>This will be filtered</somethingelse>
</details></root>';


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
//array_flip to get node names as keys for later foreach loop
$nodes = array_flip(array
(
    'person_name' => 'name',
    'mobile_no'   => 'mobile',
    'address'     => 'address',
));

$final_data = array();

//Here are all <details> sections' data in array.
$node_values = $xml->xpath('//details'); 
$node_values = json_decode(json_encode((array)$node_values), TRUE);

//this loop filters XML data from keys not existing in $nodes,
// which are the only that you want to keep
foreach($node_values as $node) {
    $final_data[] = array_intersect_key($node, $nodes);
}

var_dump($final_data);
```

I assumed, that you want to filter XML data that it's not listed in `$nodes` array. Otherwise, if you don't mind having more data than you need, you could just skip the foreach loop and use `$node_values` as your final data.

Comment: Jakub Matczak: Thanks. It works fine but if there is prefix then it gives blank output.